# Conditional query with sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

This code snippet is part of a telegram bot I am currently developing. I used the PyTelegramBotAPI package and used the @bot.callback_query_handler() to handle callback queries from users. I then created a function that prints out the last entry from a database for that particular user using the following code:

```
def splitbill(user):
    row = c.execute('SELECT * FROM database WHERE user = (?) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', user).fetchall()
    print(row[0])
```

This returned and error stating ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

```
def splitbill(user):
    row = c.execute('SELECT * FROM database WHERE user = (?) ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1', (user,)).fetchall()
    print(row[0])
```

I googled and came upon this solution by using (user,) instead of (user). But I have no idea why it worked. Can someone enlighten me? Thank you!

Comment: The second argument needs to be a sequence of some kind (list, tuple, etc) of values to bind to parameters in the query.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `(user,)` works is because the `execute` method is expecting a tuple and when you pass `(user)` without the comma, python interprets it as just `user`.

You can verify this pretty quickly in a python shell:

```py
>>> a = 'howdy'
>>> tuple = (a, )      # note the comma
>>> not_a_tuple = (a)  # note the lack of comma
>>>
>>> print(tuple)       
('howdy',)
>>> print(not_a_tuple)
howdy
>>>
>>> type(tuple)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(not_a_tuple)
<class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

(user) is interpreted as an expression whereas (user,) is always a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In Python world, single-element `tuples` are declared with `,` at the end. For example:

```
>>> p=(1)
>>> print(type(p))
<type 'int'> #--note that this is taken as an int, irrespective of the braces.
>>> q=(1,)
>>> print(type(q))
<type 'tuple'>
```

The function `c.excute` probably accepts a `tuple` of placeholders, which is the reason why your passed in `(user)` parameter wasn't considered a tuple. Good question though.